# How do I import this library in Eclipse correctly?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I want to use this language detection [library](https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/).
However, it is not a JAR file but it's just a zip archive with many folders inside. I don't know how to import something like that to use it.

This is what's inside the archive:

- doc folder
- lib folder
- src folder
- profile folder

PLease can someone help me out? How do I import this library?

EDIT: Inside the lib folder, there is a jar which I can import easily. But I don't know how to import correctly the src folder for example too.

EDIT2:
I got it working now. Trying to use the jar, it gave me an error that there is no src attached to the jar. Eclipse gave me then the option to attach the src folder afterwards. SOLVED

Comment: Don't you have a jar in your lib folder, as described in https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/wiki/GettingStarted?

Comment: please have a look at maven: https://maven.apache.org/

Comment: @Andy yes it does have a jar in the lib folder but do I import the rest like the src folder?

Comment: You don't need the src, once you have the jar imported you can import the classes/methods of the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't import the source folder, unless you want to change the code.

In Eclipse:

- Right-click your Project and select "Build Path" > "Configure Build Path"
- On the "Libraries" tab, click "Add External JARs..."
- Browse to the jar file in the `lib` folder
- On the "Libraries" tab, click the triangle to expand
- Double-click "Source attachment"
- Select "External location" and click "External Folder"
- Browse to the `src` folder.

This will allow to you see the source code, e.g. while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Add the jars from the lib directory (in the zip) into your Eclipse project. Perhaps the easiest way is to extract them and then add them.

If you need the code (the project will run fine without it, the jars are sufficient) one way is to select project properties, configure your buildpath and choose to get the src from the zip file.

[image]